# Giving ViewController access to Data and Controller Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm trying to learn good MVC practice for my iOS projects by modifying an Apple tutorial (BirdSighting), which I've successfully finished, into my own app. They built NSObject classes for the Model and Controller.  Their first ViewController is a TableVC.  In the **appDelegate.m** they altered  **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**  by connecting the firstViewController to the dataController.  In my app, I don't want my first ViewController to be a table, just a basic VC.  I get a warning: *Incompatible Pointer Types*.  Here's that code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   //  enterView is initial UIViewController
   enterView *firstViewController = (enterView *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
   //  dBcontrols is a NSObject class
   dBcontrols *aDataController = [[dBcontrols alloc] init];
   firstViewController.dataController = aDataController;   //  <-- ERROR Here.
   return YES;
}
```

My first ViewController, **enterView**, has this in the header:

```
@class contacts;
@class dBcontrols;
@interface enterView: UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) enterView *dataController;
```

My Model class, contacts, and my Controller, dBcontrols, are practically the same as in the Apple tutorial.  But the ViewController is not accessing the Controller.  In **enterView.m** are these lines:

```
#import "enterView.h"
#import "contacts.h"
#import "dBcontrols.h"

@interface enterView ()
@end

@synthesize dataController = _dataController;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   NSInteger  cntC = [self.dataController countContacts];   <--  ERROR here
   NSLog(@"number of contacts = %d", cntC );
```

}

There's an error that says: *No visible interface declares the selector 'countContacts'*, which is a Controller method found in **dBcontrols.m** like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)countContacts {
   return [self.masterContactList count];
}
```

Here's what's in the header, **dBcontrols.h**:

```
@class contacts;
@interface dBcontrols: NSObject
   - (NSUInteger)countContacts;
   . . .
@end
```

Is my problem caused by switching from a TableVC to a basic VC as the first VC?  I think that's the only relevant change from the tutorial.  How can I fix it?  I hope I've provided enough information.
Many Thanks!
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up your classes. In your app delegate, you're creating an instance of dBcontrols called aDataController, but in the header file of enterView you have dataController being an instance of the enterView class -- I think you probably meant dBcontrols there.

BTW, your code would be easier to read if you stuck with the naming convention of using capital letters to start the names of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to check these two things:

- Make sure you are importing dBcontrols.h in enterView.m

  #import "dBcontrols.h"
- Make sure there countContacts is declared in dBcontrols.h

Comment: Thanks for the response, rakmoh.  Those things were already ok.  I've edited the questions above to show them.